# Mac OS X Lion cannot access a website, but another PC on the same network can - dns issue?

Tags: macos, dns, ip

I have a Mac OS X Lion laptop and a Windows 7 machine on my network. I can access a website from one, but not the other. When I try and access this website from my Mac Safari says it cannot find the server. I have Chrome installed on the same machine and it cannot find it either.

I checked the DNS settings, adding a couple more servers to the list but this didn't help (I reordered them so I knew it was using a new DNS server).

I also flushed the DNS cache using the following command in terminal:

```
 dscacheutil -flushcache
```

That did nothing. Finally I cleared the cache in Safari, that did nothing.

Any ideas? I had a problem with this host before putting my IP on a backlist, which I was able to confirm by going through a proxy - but this time the Windows PC is okay, and they are both behind the same router and same IP.

Comment: offtopic, btw did you try by opening directly the IP address? eg. `http://100.200.100.200`

Comment: Try a `host example.com` (replace domain of course) to the website you cannot access. If the domain gets resolved, your DNS is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a DNS issue on the domain side. Still dont understand why one computer could access and another one could not. I would have thought a DNS issue would have prevented all from accessing.